# ServiceStack Swagger UI and API version number

Tags: servicestack, swagger-ui

Is there anyway to get the version number into the swagger UI?

So we can let developers know what version each deployment is at?

Comment: Did you need a global API version or specific versions for each individual API on the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible in the latest version of ServiceStack, you just set the ServiceStack API version in your AppHost thus :

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
     SetConfig(new HostConfig
     {
         ApiVersion = "1.1"
     });
{
```

This will then be picked up by the Swagger-Ui

Comment: Thank you for this simple but effective tip!

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to display the version for the API as a whole, there is support for this in Swagger UI as noted [here](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-js/pull/9). Additionally, this support made it into ServiceStack and will display properly on the bottom of the screen the same as the [Swagger example](http://swagger.wordnik.com/).

Unfortunately, there isn't yet support for accessing the `ApiVersion` property in your code as seen [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Api.Swagger/SwaggerApiService.cs#L180). This property isn't exposed in version 3 or 4 of ServiceStack or even in the new `Model` and `Property` filters on the Swagger feature. Accessing this would require a pull request to expose it.

Comment: Hi thanks for this. Do you know where I set the version so that it's picked up by swagger?

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to modify the ServiceStack code to add an ApiVersion property to the SwaggerFeature and then use it to set the property on the `ResourceResponse` returned [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Api.Swagger/SwaggerApiService.cs#L180)