# No operation matching request path "/swagger" is found

Tags: java, json, web-services, jax-rs, swagger

I am trying to implement Swagger in my web application (using Apache CXF). The following is my web.xml

```
<servlet> 
            <servlet-name>servlet_name</servlet-name> 
            <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class> 
            <init-param> 
                    <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name> 
                    <param-value> 
                            io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource, 
                            io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers, 
                            {Java_path_to_main_resource} 
                    </param-value> 
            </init-param> 
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
    </servlet> 

    <servlet> 
            <servlet-name>DefaultJaxrsConfig</servlet-name> 
            <servlet-class>io.swagger.jaxrs.config.DefaultJaxrsConfig</servlet-class> 
            <init-param> 
                    <param-name>api.version</param-name> 
                    <param-value>1.0.0</param-value> 
            </init-param> 
            <init-param> 
                    <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name> 
                    <param-value>http://localhost:6789/</param-value> 
            </init-param> 
            <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup> 
    <servlet>
```

This is the dependency in my pom.xml

```
<dependency> 
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId> 
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId> 
        <version>1.5.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

However, when I run my application, and try to hit the endpoint at http://localhost.6789/swagger.json, I get the following error:

> org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils - No operation matching request
>   path "/swagger" is found, HTTP Method: GET, ContentType: */*, Accept:
>   application/json. Please enable FINE?TRACE log level for more details.

I'm not sure when I'm doing wrong. I've followed the same examples as many of the codes on github, but have been unsuccessful at this point. Also, I am able to hit the endpoint for other paths in my application, so I know that it has been deployed successfully.

Comment: I see a few issues.  you're using a resteasy specific param name to try to configure CXF for one.  Did you try using an implementation of `Application` instead? What container are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean on several fronts. First, the resteasy specific name is mainly down to this example: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5. Also, how can I try an implementation of Application? And what do you mean by container? Sorry for the misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: you can check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783349/setting-the-api-version-with-swagger-ui/35790642#35790642