# Jersey + Swagger + Swagger-UI + Maven configuration

Tags: eclipse, maven, jersey, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying swagger for the first time with Jersey and Maven, and I am wondering if I am going down the right path. I have jersey, maven, and swagger working on my local computer. Soon, I want to deploy it to different environments and include swagger-ui.

1. If I configure my web.xml file to `<param-value>http://localhost:8080/api</param-value>` then I see that swagger works on my local computer. But will I need to change this address every time I want to deploy my code to different environments (for example going from a Dev environment, to QA environment, to Production environment), and if so how would I go about doing that or is it not possible/not what swagger is meant for?
2. I want to incorporate swagger-ui with my project. I see online suggestions of downloading the file manually from git and placing it in my project. But what I am wondering is if there is a maven dependency that I can use instead so that I can use maven to get the necessary code to use swagger-ui and configure it to work with jersey. If so what is the dependency and how do I use it to deploy the code through multiple environments?

Please give guidance and links to tutorials if possible seeing as I am new to this technology. Also if I am way off in my thought process of using jersey/swagger/swagger-ui/maven without manually downloading code from git and being able to deploy the code through multiple environments please let me know so I can look for another way to use REST in my application.

Thank you for your help.

pom.xml:

```
    <repositories>
      <repository>
          <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
          <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
          <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
      </repository>
  </repositories>

  <properties>
      <jersey2.version>2.19</jersey2.version>
      <jaxrs.version>2.0.1</jaxrs.version>
  </properties>

  <!-- Dependencies -->
  <dependencies>


    <!-- JAX-RS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxrs.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Jersey 2.19 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

     <!-- Servlet Library -->
     <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
     <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.0</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>

     <!-- Spring dependencies -->
     <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
         <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>

     <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
         <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>

     <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
         <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>

    <!-- Junit -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

  <display-name>HelloWorldSpring</display-name>

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
          org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>    

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
           <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
           <param-value>
           io.swagger.jaxrs.listing, 
           com.jer.rest
           </param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Jersey2Config</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>io.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>api.version</param-name>
          <param-value>1.0.0</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
          <param-value>http://localhost:8080/HealthTracker/rest</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

   <!-- Other XML Configuration -->
  <!-- Load by Spring ContextLoaderListener -->
  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/root-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>


   <!-- Spring ContextLoaderListener -->
  <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I think would answer your questions:

1. To be able to configure swagger as per different environments, then these are the steps you can follow:

   i) Create a Bootstrap class to configure swagger bean (ref: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5  and [Setting the Api Version with Swagger UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783349/setting-the-api-version-with-swagger-ui/35790642#35790642))

   ii) Set the values in the above bean using values from a properties file, which you can easily configure outside your code in any environment.
2. Swagger dist consists of html/css/image/js files. It cannot be added as a Maven jar dependency.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Check out the link https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-samples/tree/2.0/java

It has excellent examples on how to configure Swagger 3.0 in your project (see java-jersey2-webxml example). For earlier versions check the branches

As far as the ui is concerned, you can download required files or you can just add the below dependency in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

It will download necessary ui files. You can copy the downloaded index.html in your project and edit the url.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution with java doclets (no swagger annotations are required). Use the [maven-javadoc-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/) and configure the [swagger-doclet](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.carma/swagger-doclet/1.1.2) as an [alternate doclet](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/alternate-doclet.html). With [maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) it is possible to manage different environments:

```
<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-service-docs</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <doclet>com.carma.swagger.doclet.ServiceDoclet</doclet>
                            <docletArtifact>
                                <groupId>com.carma</groupId>
                                <artifactId>swagger-doclet</artifactId>
                                <version>1.0.3</version>
                            </docletArtifact>
                            <reportOutputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</reportOutputDirectory>
                            <useStandardDocletOptions>false</useStandardDocletOptions>
                            <additionalparam>-apiVersion 1 -docBasePath
                                https://example.com/apidocs -apiBasePath
                                https://example.com/api -swaggerUiPath
                                ../../../src/main/resources/swagger-ui/
                            </additionalparam>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>javadoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

I put the swagger resources directly into my project. So it was easy to customize the css and html.

[image: swagger-resources]

Or, if you do not want to put swagger into your repository, you could use the [frotend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) to manage your js/css dependencies (like: [swagger-ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/bower.json)) with [bower](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin#running-bower).

I deliver swagger as static resources from the embedded server directly (in my case I used grizzly) :

```
String apiDocs = Env.getApiDocs();         
server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(
    new CLStaticHttpHandler(GrizzlyStarter.class.getClassLoader(), apiDocs), apiDocs);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with the same problem and created a library that if included into a Jersey project will add swagger 3.0 UI. Please take a look [code](https://github.com/avinokurov/itzap-jerseyswagger-starter) and [blog post](http://itzap.com/swagger-ui-in-jersey-api/) The idea is that all swagger UI static content is packaged withing the library and extracted at runtime. In addition, library will take care of creating web context for swagger UI and adjust reference to the `openapi.json` file. You will need to add 2 properties and this code to your project:

```
SwaggerContext.addSwaggerServlet(tomcat, context,
    ConfigBuilder.builder(ConfigType.TYPE_SAFE)
            .build()
            .getConfig("swagger"),
    EmailApplication.class);
```

and properties:

```
swagger.package="com.itzap"
swagger.apiBaseUrl="http://{application url}"
```

If all other configuration is left at defaults swagger UI can be accessed over this URL:

```
http://{application base URL}/api/v1/swagger
```